# Samsung I5503 Arabic Froyo

Tags: 2.2-froyo, rom, languages, samsung-galaxy-5

Is there any **Arabic** Froyo rom for I5503 (Galaxy 5)?

Comment: I can't find one.  It may be possible to extract the language from Eclair and add it to a Froyo ROM, but I'm not sure.  Have you asked your carrier?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be one right now. Check [SamFirmware](http://www.samfirmware.com/android.htm) for official ROM updates. (note - that's not an official site, they just host the official firmwares).

[This site](http://blog.mutu.org/iptek/how-to-add-arabic-language-on-samsung-galaxy-5.html) describes how to install a 2.1 Arabic ROM on a Galaxy 5. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

you can install [Mirsal](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.arabic.smsviewer) it's a prog that read arabic SMS but for entire arabic Rom.. if you find one plzzz inform me

Comment: That same developer also has other apps that help you use Android in Arabic including an Arabic keyboard, Notepad and Contacts viewer. https://market.android.com/developer?pub=Aziz+Huss